# Khan academy: JavaScript loop taking too long

Tags: javascript, khan-academy

[image]

I'm reading through the khan academy course on algorithms. I'm at https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/insertion-sort/p/challenge-implement-insertion-sort. So far I have:

```
var insert = function(array, rightIndex, value) {
for(var j = rightIndex;
    j >= 0 && array[j] > value;
    j--) {
    array[j + 1] = array[j];
}   
array[j + 1] = value; 
};

var insertionSort = function(array) {

for(var i= 1;  i < array.length ; i++ ) {
    insert(array, i ,array[i+1] );
}

};

var array = [22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42];
insertionSort(array);
```

You can see the line of code in the screenshot which appears to be the problem , but it looks fine to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Instead of looping over the array length (since you are constantly adding items to it), loop over a copy: `var insertionSort = function(array) {
    var copy = array.slice();
    for(var i= 0;  i < copy.length ; i++ ) {
        insert(array, i ,array[i+1] );
    }
};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re starting `rightIndex` off at `i` and moving the value `array[i + 1]`, but `i` reaches `array.length` and `insert` starts by setting the element at `rightIndex + 1`. This will cause the array to grow.

Move the current element and start at the previous index instead:

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    insert(array, i - 1,array[i]);
}
```

One way to catch this when debugging is to *seal* your array so it can’t grow:

```
var array = Object.seal([22, 11, 99, 88, 9, 7, 42]);
```

**This only works in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), though.** If you’re in sloppy mode, it will just hide mistakes.